# Can a user connected as sysdba always bypass auditing mechanisms?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, audit, users, sysdba

Can a user connected as `sysdba` always bypass auditing mechanisms? What could be done to minimize (or prevent) auditing prevention?

Comment: Seriously,  why login as sysdba for normal use?.

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of sysdba user. If you like to prevent that, then revoke this privilege from Oracle user and prevent that the os user can become `oracle`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Even if  `AUDIT_SYS_OPERATIONS` is set to `true`?

Comment: I am not an admin, so I don't know. In Oracle you have different types of administrator accounts. I am quite sure in terms of security/auditing you can do almost everything. I remember an Oracle advertisement where it said: "Prevent that your DBA knows the financial statement before the CEO does."

Comment: Ultimately you cannot protect data from everybody. Somebody has to be trusted. If not the DBAs, then whoever has the "oracle" password on the OS who can circumvent any database-level security put in place. And if not them, your Unix admins with "root" access. And if not them, the folks in the server room with physical access to the machines. Let's face it - all of these levels are going to have the ability to access database contents, just like someone in the bank has access to the vault. You have to trust someone. Hopefully your DBAs are trustworthy enough. If not, they shouldn't have sysdba.

Comment: Generally all SYS actions are audited by default, though depending on whether you are using Unified Auditing the results may not go to the same place as other audit data. Before unified auditing, SYS entries were sent to an OS audit trail or to syslog. Every SQL command should be recorded, though SYS would still be exempt from "normal" audit policies.